# How to get a flyout on a button click where the button is in another flyout in uwp

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp

I am using flyout control in my uwp app. I want to display a flyout on a button click and that button is in another flyout.
I want the GUI like this in image.

[image: The GUI I need is]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (try the search box above) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. Most importantly include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Any updates? Did my answer solve you problem?

Comment: No it is not relevant to my question. Any way we r not taking 2 flyouts instead doing it in other way.

Answer (score 3):

> A single object element that declares the content. This must be an object that has UIElement in its hierarchy (plain strings don't work). This can be a container, such as a Panel derived class, so that multiple content items within the Flyout can be arranged in layout.

For more info, see [Flyout class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.aspx).

So we can add another Button to the content of the Flyout.

Also we can use [`FlyoutPlacementMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutplacementmode.aspx) enumeration set to the [`FlyoutBase.Placement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase.placement.aspx) to set the location of the flyout is above the target element.

For example:

```
<Button Name="MyButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
Content="Open flyout">
<Button.Flyout>
    <Flyout Placement="Right">
        <Grid Width="300" Height="300">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition  Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition  Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition  Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition  Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition  Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button  Grid.Row="0" Content="Open second flyout">
                <Button.Flyout>
                    <Flyout Placement="Left">
                        <Grid Width="300" Height="300">
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is some text in a flyout." />
                        </Grid>
                    </Flyout>
                </Button.Flyout>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Flyout>
</Button.Flyout>
```

If you want to show a menu of items, please try to use [`MenuFlyout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyout.aspx) control. For more info, including XAML and code examples, see Quickstart: [Adding a MenuFlyout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn308516.aspx).